# AWS cloudformation launching ec2 instance with classic link enabled

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch ec2 instance using clodfomation, with classic link enabled to vpc. 
I don't see any settings on:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [Launch Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-classiclinkvpcid) as a part of an autoscaling group, but as far as I know you can't do it in CloudFormation for a single instance.

If you want to go ahead with this, add an ASG to your stack with MinSize, MaxSize, and DesiredCapacity all set to 1.